# Quotient ring calculation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'd love to show $\mathbb{R}[s,u,t] / (su, t(s+u)-1) = \mathbb{R}[s,t]/(ts-1) \times \mathbb{R}[u,t]/(tu-1)$. Is there any suggestion for this calculation?

Edit: What I get is $(ts-1)(tu-1) = t^2(su) - [t(s+u)-1]$. Is this useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

''Edit: What I get is $(ts−1)(tu−1)=t^2(su)−[t(s+u)−1]$. Is this useful?''

This shows that $(ts-1)(tu-1)$ lies in the ideal $\langle su,t(s+u)-1\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. I can show that now!